# Outputting table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is an exercise from DataQuest and the data can be found here:

https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/2017-new-coder-survey

How do I generate a table from variables with pandas in jupyter?

```
CountryLive_abs = survey['CountryLive'].value_counts()
CountryLive_rel = survey['CountryLive'].value_counts(normalize=True)
CountryLive_abs.head(10)
```

[image: Table with absolute frequency]

I would like ['Country, 'Absolute Frequency', 'Relative Frequency'] as the headers.

I was googling around and found plotly but I got:

```
import plotly.plotly as py

CountryLive_abs = survey['CountryLive'].value_counts()
CountryLive_rel = survey['CountryLive'].value_counts(normalize=True)

table = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=['Country','Absolute Frequency','Relative Frequency']),
    cells=dict(values=[[CountryLive_abs],
                       [CountryLive_rel]]))

data = [table]
py.iplot(data)

# ImportError: No module named 'plotly'
```

So I'm wondering if pandas have their own table function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for `DataFrame` from both `Series`:

```
df = pd.concat([CountryLive_abs, CountryLive_rel], axis=1).reset_index()
df.columns = ['Country','Absolute Frequency','Relative Frequency']
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I wanted to not show the index column? I tried using drop=True on reset_index() but it gave me a length mismatch error. # ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values have 3 elements

Comment: @Julian - Do you think `df.to_string(index=False)` ? Or what is reason for remove `index` ?

Comment: I just wanted a cleaner look. Or is it not pythonic to remove the index? I'm new to coding.

Comment: @Julian Obviously there is no reason for remove index. Only if dont want write index of dataframe to file use `df. to_csv(file, index=False)`

Comment: @Julian If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it. Or if need some more info, let me know. Thanks.